# Element adjacent to TextBox using AdornedElementPlaceholder

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBox`, I am trying to place a `TextBlock` adjacent to `TextBox` using `AdornedElementPlaceholder` when the `TextBox` has focus. But after reading from MSDN, I found that `AdornedElementPlaceholder` can only be used for `ValidationError`.

I have used a `Grid` with column, but this is tacking the actual `TextBox` width that I have set in XAML, I dont want to interfere the `TextBox`, just want to place a element next to it, irrespective of Width.

Adding a sample image, this image is part of Error Template I created for Validation. But I cant use ValidationTemplate here.

[image: Image Sample]

Please put light on this question.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code

Comment: Pictures would also be helpful. Not entirely sure how you want these elements to look.

Comment: I have added a sample image, this I created for Error Validation using ValidationTemplate

Comment: I want to achieve this without using error template, but something like this using AdornedElementPlaceHolder